Calculating Degree and Creating Degree Matrices for Bipartite Network in Python
I am trying to follow a research paper for my academics and I am trying to re-create what the author had put inside this paper.
About
I have a dataset of claims and parties. Each claim is associated with one or more parties. I want to create a bipartite network from this data, with claims on one side and three types of nodes(p1, p2, and p3) on the other.
I have created a dummy DataFrame df that looks like this:
data = {
    'claims': ['C001',  'C001', 'C003', 'C003', 'C002'],
    'parties': ['p1',  'p2', 'p3', 'p1', 'p1']
}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

I’m trying to calculate the degree of each claim and each party and create degree matrices for claims and parties. The degree of a node in a network is the number of connections or edges the node has to other nodes. In my bipartite network:
The degree of a claim node would be the number of parties involved in that claim.
The degree of a party node would be the number of claims that the party is involved in.
I’m also trying to calculate the mean, median, minimum, and maximum degree for each party type individually.
My Code so Far- I have created the bipartite graph and now I’m not sure how to proceed from there. Any help would be appreciated!
import networkx as nx
from networkx.algorithms import bipartite

G= nx.Graph()
G.add_nodes_from(df['claims'], bipartite=0)
G.add_nodes_from(df['parties'], bipartite=1)
for i, row in df.iterrows():
   G.add_edge(row['claims'], row['parties'])

Expected Output:
I would like to create a table similar to “Table 2” in the research paper I mentioned. This table should contain the following columns:

Set: This column should contain the set name (either C for claims or P for parties).
Type: This column should contain the type of node (for example, Claim, p1, p2, or p3).
Nodes: The column Nodes shows the relative frequency of a specific node type within the set of parties (we can skip this part
for claims).
Edges: The column Edges shows the relative frequency of edges connected to the respective node type in the set of all edges. As an
edge always connects one claim and one party, the edge can be
attributed to just the party.
Mean degree: This column should contain the mean degree of each type of node.
Median degree: This column should contain the median degree of each type of node.
Min degree: This column should contain the minimum degree of each type of node.
Max degree: This column should contain the maximum degree of each type of node.

The Table should look like this: I am not sure how to calculate all these values.



Set
Type
Nodes
Edges
Mean degree
Median degree
Min degree
Max degree




C
Claim
-
-






P
p1








P
p2








P
p3









The table should be populated with data from my dataset.
Output from Research Paper
Summary Table

Creating a graph to represent your data is unnecessary.  Much more straightforward would be to load your  data into a relational database and use SQL to extract what you need.

Thank you for your suggestion @ravenspoint. I understand where you’re coming from, However, in this case, I am specifically interested in creating a bipartite network as described in the research paper I mentioned. The network representation will allow me to calculate the individual degrees of each party and create degree matrices, which are crucial for my analysis. Additionally, the network structure will be useful for other parts of my project that involve network analysis methods.

@BayekShiva I don't get how you could get an average per party. One party has a given number of neighbors, for instance p1 has 3, how would you get a min/max/avg from that?

IIUC, you can just use set operations and degree, since you should never have edges between claims or between parties:
# G = nx.from_pandas_edgelist(df, source='claims', target='parties')

claims = set(df['claims'])
parties = set(df['parties'])

claim_degrees = {n: G.degree(n) for n in claims}
# {'C003': 2, 'C001': 2, 'C002': 1}

parties_degrees = {n: G.degree(n) for n in parties}
# {'p2': 1, 'p1': 3, 'p3': 1}

pd.Series(claim_degrees).agg(['min', 'max', 'mean', 'median'])
# min       1.000000
# max       2.000000
# mean      1.666667
# median    2.000000
# dtype: float64
    
pd.Series(parties_degrees).agg(['min', 'max', 'mean', 'median'])
# min       1.000000
# max       3.000000
# mean      1.666667
# median    1.000000
# dtype: float64

Note that you can get the same in pure pandas without networkx:
df.groupby('claims')['parties'].nunique().agg(['min', 'max', 'mean', 'median'])
# min       1.000000
# max       2.000000
# mean      1.666667
# median    2.000000
# dtype: float64
    
df.groupby('parties')['claims'].nunique().agg(['min', 'max', 'mean', 'median'])
# min       1.000000
# max       3.000000
# mean      1.666667
# median    1.000000
# dtype: float64


Thank you for your response @mozway. I appreciate your time and effort. However, I think there might have been a misunderstanding about what I’m trying to achieve. Let me clarify. I want to calculate the individual degree of each party in my case (p1, p2, p3), and their (mean, median, min, and max) degree. I have also attached the author's output from the research paper in my question, where (policyholder, garage, and broker) represent the parties (p1, p2, p3) in my data.
P.S.- This is just a sample dataset so it may look weird to calculate the summary stats for each individual parties.

@Bayek To be explicit, please provide the exact expected output as edit to your question. If your current example is not meaningful for a computation, please update it. We need to be able to understand the logic/computation without needing to read the paper (questions should be self contained). If this helps, please break down the computation for one of the parties.

Thank you for your feedback @mozway. I have updated my question to provide more clarity. The dataset I provided for the example is indeed correct for computation.

Your code for calculating the claim_degrees is indeed correct. I am only concerned with the parties_degree.
